# Laravel testing migrating pollutes assertions

Tags: laravel, testing, phpunit, assert

While writing tests for my Laravel package I came across something strange. My empty tests were passing instead of marked as "Risky".

Further investigation led me to the `PendingCommand` class that has a [`run()`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/6.x/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/PendingCommand.php#L130) method which makes an assertion on the exit code of the command. This `PendingCommand` was instantiated by calling `$this->astisan('migrate:fresh')->run()`. I was able to skip this assertion by calling [`assertExitCode(null)`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/6.x/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/PendingCommand.php#L108) before running the command. It worked but there is still an assertion happening.

Anybody had this problem before and/or was able to prevent assertions from happening before the actual test is executed?

It would be nice to see which assertions are being made, but I was unable to find this. The only thing I could find was that the `Assert` class keeps a [`$count`](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/blob/master/src/Framework/Assert.php#L71) of all the assertions done, not which one.

I will continue my search for a solution and post my findings to this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that `InteractsWithConsole` has a [`withoutMockingConsoleOutput`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/6.x/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/Concerns/InteractsWithConsole.php#L64) method that will prevent a mock [to be created](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/6.x/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/PendingCommand.php#L161) with assertions.

Final code:

```php
$this->withoutMockingConsoleOutput()
    ->artisan('migrate:fresh');
```